# Multiple google map on modal view Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a list of enterprices and need to display a map on their respective modal, for this I have this:

```
<div class="row" id="googleMap<%=enterprice.id%>" style="width 100%; height: 300px;" data1='<%=enterprice.latitud%>' data2='<%=enterprice.longitud%>'>
</div>
```

this code is on a html.erb file.

My function for loading the map:

```
<script>
  function myMap(lat, long) {
    var uluru = { lat: lat, lng: long};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: uluru
    });
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: uluru,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
```

And a jquery helper for passing the data

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
                $('#googleMap<%=enterprice.id%>').each(function (index, element) {
                  var $this = $(element);
                  myMap($this.attr("data1"), $this.attr("data2"));
                });
              });
```

The problem is the map is only loading on the modal for the first cell, but not actually displaying any map.

And the other cells wont even load the map.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need a map and a modal for each. You can have one and change them using JS. This way you will not overload your page with elements you will only use in series but never together in parallel.

You can have a map defined in your modal whenever the page is ready.

```
<script>
      var map;
      var old_marker;

      function initMap() {
        var point = {lat: 0, lng: 0};

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: point,
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        // This event listener will call addMarker() when the map is clicked.
        map.addListener('click', function(event) {
          addMarker(event.latLng);
        });

        // Adds a marker at the center of the map.
        addMarker(point);
      }

      // Adds a marker to the map and push to the array.
      function addMarker(location) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: location,
          map: map
        });
        if(old_marker){
          old_marker.setMap(null)
        }
        old_marker = marker
        markers.push(marker);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
</script>
```

Now we have to add a marker for each enterprise just by clicking on them.
I suggest adding a certain class to them

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  initMap();
  $(.enterprise).click(function(){
    addMarker($this.attr("data1"), $this.attr("data2"));
  });
});
```

By this, a marker will be added on the click on each enterprise and the map will focus that location. Now all you need to do is show the Modal.

**References:** `https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-remove`